# Wordpress site sits idle before loading the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website, that is loading extremely slow.

```
http://shop.fertan.bg
```

The issue is that the website sits ideal for long time before beginning to load the webpage. I am unable to isolate the issue, as I used same theme and plugins (and few other extra plugins) on my other website,

```
http://52.57.164.181/
```

This page is loading extremely smooth and fast.

Has anyone had the same issue before? and help me understand this!

Comment: what server are you running at your first site and what on your second

Comment: Both are on apache server, the one with the issue is on shared hosting and the other one is on AWS EC2.

Comment: But the site, http://fertan.bg is having same issue and it is on AWS EC2 and hosted along side http://52.57.164.181/. http://fertan.bg  is replicated version of http://shop.fertan.bg

Comment: http://shop.fertan.bg/ is russian ?

Comment: I think it's Bulgarian (the content is managed by someone else)